# What is the difference between vmWare Workstation and vmWare vSphere?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, vsphere

It may be a dumb question, I already did googling but did not get a clear answer for me:

What is the difference between vmWare Workstation and vmWare vSphere?

Can vSphere be used instead of Workstation?

Comment: Old question, but the short answer is:  
- Workstation is for endusers / home   
- vSphere is for Enterprise / Business

Comment: And to be pedantic, the company capitalizes it like so: VMware

Answer (score 1):

There are quite different products. Vmware Workstation is a type-2 hypervisor while ESX/vSphere is a type-1 hypervisor.

Very simplified: This means that vmware workstation runs on top of an OS, while a type-1 does not.

> Can vSphere be used instead of Workstation?

Yes. Both can be used. But they are not equally good for the same tasks.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually very similar in that they are both hypervisors that offer virtualization. The difference is where the virtualization takes place.

Vsphere is a native or bare-metal hypervisor, running directly on the host's hardware. This is to do things like manage guest operating systems.

Workstation is not directly running on the hardware but instead hosted on the OS, as a program. This is to do things like run an OS as a sandbox from a different OS.

You can use either or both, but neither is intended to be a replacement for the other.